# Which method is being called after popBackStack?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity where I am calling three fragments - each depending on each other:

A(ctivity) -> f1 (Fragment one, title {is|should}: list) -> f2 (Fragment two, title {is|should}: overview) -> f3  (Fragment three, title {is|should}: detail)

ATM I use the following method call to jump backwards:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
    }
}
```

This works fine.

I am overriding the ActionBar title in each fragment like this:

```
ActionBar bar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
bar.setTitle(R.string.title_f3);
```

When navigating forward (like shown above) this works flawlessly but navigating backwards the title of the ActionBar isn´t updated:

f3 (title {is|should}: detail) -> f2 (title {is}: detail, {should}: overview) -> f1 (title {is}: detail, {should}: list)

Obviously I could just update it again when the fragment is shown. But my debugger never stops in any of the methods I´d except which would be called like *onResume()*.

So is there actually any method being called in a previous fragment after *popBackStack()* ?

Comment: If you return, perhaps you'd like to choose an answer for closures sake! :)

Comment: Hi there @OpenHaus, could you select an answer to this question if any satisfied your query please and thank you! :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I know this is a bit late for an answer but for anyone who navigates here this might help!

First thing is first: popBackStack()doesn't pop a fragment, it pops a fragment transaction. So the last fragment transaction is reversed upon being called. If you were displaying FragmentA currently and your transaction was:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_layout, fragmentB);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It would replace FragmentA with FragmentB, and add that transaction (not the fragment) to the back stack. If you then hit the back button, it pops the transaction off the back stack, which was "replace this FragmentA with a FragmentB". Essentially, this instruction reverses the last transaction and removes it from the stack of transactions carried out. If the original FragmentA still exists, it uses that one. If it's been destroyed, it makes a new one.

So, if the Fragment hasn't been destroyed, then recalling the fragment after using on popBackStack(), the onStart() and onResume() methods are called. If the Fragment has been destroyed previously, then the lifecycle methods will be called starting from onAttach(). It's the same as pressing the back button on Activities.

Now the important bit, what happens re fragment lifecycle when we pop off back stack? Well as said before the fragment transaction is reversed so:

Scenario 1: Your fragmentB didn't already exist before transaction.
In this case the onCreate() and onAttach() methods are called during the transaction so the fragment will be destroyed and detached if you call popBackStack() and reverse the transaction (Note FragmentA probably already existed so replacing it wont destroy it as we're not undoing a fragment creation). In this case the lifecycle methods will be called starting from onAttach().

Scenario 2: Your fragmentB did already exist before transaction. In this case the fragment won't be destroyed and the next time you access it the onStart() and onResume() methods are called.

[image: Fragment Lifecycle]

This fellow here explains a few things about using popbackstack() http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/19/transaction-backstack-and-its-management/ and the fragment lifecycle http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/22/fragment-view-state-retention-a-dirty-solution/. The other related posts are worth reading too!

Comment: I checked it out . in that scenario when the fragment is not destroyed , fragment OnResume is never called when user hit the back button and popbackStack run . I need a method for calling my function of my interface to show or hide Toolbar. maybe using "addOnBackStackChangedListener" in mainActivty is the answer.

Answer (score 8):

use addOnBackStackChangedListener method in your BaseActivity, which will be called any time backstack changes

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    if (fm != null) {
                        int backStackCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
                        if (backStackCount == 0) {
                            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
                            }
                            setToolbarTittle(R.string.app_name);
                        } else {
                            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

My workaround is to get the current title of the actionbar in the Fragment before setting it to the new title. This way, once the Fragment is popped, I can change back to that title.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Get/Backup current title
    mTitle = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
            .getTitle();
    // Set new title
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
        .setTitle(R.string.this_fragment_title);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Set title back
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
        .setTitle(mTitle);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Nice workaround. Exactly what I was looking for.!

Answer (score 2):

There's also one other good [source](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/) that you can read through.

I think, the important point is the difference of the transaction you performed on Fragment B. If it's **add**, then no lifecycle methods are called on **Fragment A**, if it's **replace**, you will get some calls on those methods.

Answer (score -1):

I use following workaround:

1) set 1st fragment `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` before add 2nd fragment on top of 1st one.

2) set 1st fragment `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`  in `onOptionsItemSelected()` after return from 2nd fragment.

3) `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of 1st fragment should be called and you can change actionbar here.

But I want to know a better solution.

Comment: My solution now is to override the `onBackPressed()` method and set the title accordingly.

Answer (score -4):

You can find a nice `Fragment` lifecycle diagram in the android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). So yes, if the fragment is brought to the foreground from the backstack `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are called.

Comment: I do know the lifecycle and the methods mentioned. As I described in detail in my question none of these methods get called. That's why I asked.

Comment: The way to this I think will be to add a custom method to your fragments, override onBackPressed (or through [OnBackStackChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html)), get the currently visible fragment and call your custom method.