# Preference Fragment with popBackStack transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-settings

After deep dive into stackoverflow to find similar situation and no luck I decided to post my question. For my android app I have a settings (MySettings.java) `PreferenceFragmentCompat` which in turn on button click popups a list (MyList.java) `ListFragment` and after the item choose saves it and closes the list fragment. The fragments switch implemented as follow:

**MySettings.java**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {
    // data load from SharedPreferences 
}

...

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, MyList.class).addToBackStack().commit();
```

**MyList.java**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // data save into SharedPreferences

    ...

    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

So, after the list fragment is closed and it's returns back to settings fragment I want to show (load) previously saved item, namely I added [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onResume()) (suggested in [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870210/)) method in turn triggers loading data function. But loading process is not triggered after `.popBackStack()`

What I'm doing wrong?
Is it generally possible to achieve this for settings concept with usage of fragments? Or there is better way? If so, please share your experience(s).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`onResume` refers to the `Activity` and is only called when the `Activity` is resumed. As you use `ft.replace` the preference fragment is recreated, when calling `popBackStack()`.

Thus you can put the `loadData()` in the `onCreateView()` method of your preference fragment.

Comment: The method [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onResume()) also exits for Fragments and it's `called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity#onResume() of the containing Activity's lifecycle`.

Comment: No, namely after I added onCreateView method which in turn calls loadData() function on popBackStack() call it's (MySettings fragment) doesn't calls loadData().

Comment: But it is not called again, when you run `popBackStack()`?