# How to call a function when fragment transaction is reversed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to run some code in a fragment after `popBackStack()` is called in a fragment transaction. Typically I would run the code in `onStart()` of the fragment, however this does not get called when a transaction is reversed using `popBackStack()`.

MainActivity:

FragmentBrowse -> FragmentItemDetails -> FragmentItemDetails -> FragmentItemDetails...

As you can see `FragmentItemDetails` can be opened over and over on top of each other.

When an item is clicked in the Browse/ItemDetails fragment it runs this code:

```
transaction
        .add(R.id.fragment_browse_layout, itemDetailFragment)
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
        .addToBackStack(item.item_name)
        .commit()
```

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:
After pressing the back button in the 4th `ItemDetailFragment`, run some code in the 3rd `ItemDetailFragment`, similar to `onResume` or `onStart()`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305887/7412501) claims that "if the Fragment hasn't been destroyed, then recalling the fragment after using on `popBackStack()`, the `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods are called".

I've tried using `onStart()` `onResume()` `onCreate()` `onAttach()` even `onHiddenChanged()`. None of these get called.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are using `add()`, then that has absolutely zero effect on any other fragment (you're only adding a fragment). Maybe what you're actually looking for is `replace()`, which *will* cause your previous fragment to go through lifecycle events when you return to it.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!